# Spring MVC HTTP Status 400 -

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc

I am trying to create a program where I am getting the error

Edit.jsp

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" %>
<%@taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" prefix="form" %>
<%@taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
<html>
<body>
<c:if test="${session_username != null }">Hello ${session_username}!</c:if>
    <font face="verdana" size="2">
        ${welcomeMessage} <BR><BR>
        <form:form action="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/editemployee" method="POST" modelAttribute="editForm">
            <form:errors path="studenterrors" />
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="2" align="center">Spring MVC Form Demo - Edit</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>User Name</td>
                    <td><form:input path="username" /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>First Name</td>
                    <td><form:input path="firstname" /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Last Name</td>
                    <td><form:input path="lastname" /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Mobile No.</td>
                    <td><form:input path="mobileno" /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Password</td>
                    <td><form:password path="password" /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Email</td>
                    <td><form:input path="email" /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>BirthDate (mm/dd/yyyy)</td>
                    <td><form:input path="birthdate" /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Profession</td>
                    <td><form:select path="profession" items="${professionList}" /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="2" align="center"><input type="submit" value="Submit" /></td>
                </tr>                                   
            </table>                                        
        </form:form>
    </font> 
</body>
</html>
```

LoginSuccess.java

```
package java4s;


import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Scope;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.ModelMap;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

import java4s.EmployeeService;

@Controller
public class LoginSuccessController {

    @Autowired
    EmployeeService emp_service;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/editemployee", method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public ModelAndView EditSaveMyInfo(ModelMap model, @ModelAttribute("editForm") Employee employee) {

        model.addAttribute("message", "Information Updated");
        return new ModelAndView("EditSuccess",model);
    }

}
```

Whenever I click on submit button, I get `HTTP Status 400 -` error. But when I remove `@ModelAttribute("editForm") Employee employee` from the function `EditSaveMyInfo`, the error doesnt appears?

How can I solve the error?

EDIT

Employee.java

```
package java4s;

import java.util.Date;

public class Employee {

    private String userid;
    private String firstname;
    private String lastname;    
    private String mobileno;
    private String username;
    private String password;
    private String email;
    private Date birthDate;
    private String profession;
    private String studenterrors;

    public String getUserid()
    {
        return userid;
    }
    public void setUserid(String userid)
    {
        this.userid = userid;
    }

    public String getUsername()
    {
        return username;
    }
    public void setUsername(String username)
    {
        this.username = username;
    }
    public String getFirstname()
    {
        return firstname;
    }
    public void setFirstname(String firstname)
    {
        this.firstname = firstname;
    }
    public String getLastname()
    {
        return lastname;
    }
    public void setLastname(String lastname)
    {
        this.lastname = lastname;
    }
    public String getMobileno()
    {
        return mobileno;
    }
    public void setMobileno(String mobileno)
    {
        this.mobileno = mobileno;
    }

    public String getPassword()
    {
        return password;
    }
    public void setPassword(String password)
    {
        this.password = password;
    }
        public String getEmail()
    {
        return email;
    }
    public void setEmail(String email)
    {
        this.email = email;
    }
        public Date getBirthdate()
    {
        return birthDate;
    }
    public void setBirthdate(Date birthDate)
    {
        this.birthDate = birthDate;
    }
        public String getProfession()
    {
        return profession;
    }
    public void setProfession(String profession)
    {
        this.profession = profession;
    }
        public String getstudenterrors()
    {
        return studenterrors;
    }
    public void setstudenterrors(String studenterrors)
    {
        this.studenterrors = studenterrors;
    }
}
```

Comment: can you pls share edit form

Comment: You mean `EditSuccess.jsp` page?

Comment: @AjmalMuhammad, updated the code.

Comment: @HarshitShrivastava what is the exact error trace you are getting? I am not able to reproduce the error with your code and able to see my `EditSuccess` page

Comment: @TimeTravel, When I remove `<form:input path="birthdate" />`, then it works fine. The error description is `The request sent by the client was syntactically incorrect`

Comment: @HarshitShrivastava   what is the date(format) u r trying to give as input?

Answer (score 1):

use `@RequestBody @Valid Employee employee`  instead of `@ModelAttribute("editForm") Employee employee`

and you controller become

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/editemployee", method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public ModelAndView EditSaveMyInfo(ModelMap model, @RequestBody @Valid Employee employee,BindingResult result) {
    if (result.hasErrors()) {
        throw new BadRequestException();
    }   model.addAttribute("message", "Information Updated");
        return new ModelAndView("EditSuccess",model);
    }
```

binding result object is used for catch bad request exception.
this is the spring standard

Comment: import javax.validation.Valid; use this header file

Comment: Importing it giving the error. It seems you have used some other spring libraries which is not present in my system.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that the binding between the *form* and the *model(Employee)* was failed.

Change your controller (*Just read it very carefully, you will get a picture about how binding actually works*) to :

```
package java4s;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Scope;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.ModelMap;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

import java4s.EmployeeService;

@Controller
public class LoginSuccessController {

    @Autowired
    EmployeeService emp_service;

   //Give you a form (edit.jsp) as response after binding happens
   @RequestMapping(value = "/employeeform", method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public ModelAndView doBinding() {
       ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView("edit", "employee", new Employee()); 
            return mv;

    }


  // Now the form comes here after it gets submitted.
 // And you can start populating the fields
    @RequestMapping(value = "/saveemployee", method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public ModelAndView EditSaveMyInfo(ModelMap model, @ModelAttribute("employee") Employee employee) {

        model.addAttribute("message", "Information Updated");
        return new ModelAndView("EditSuccess",model);
    }

}
```

And change your `edit.jsp` to :

- (Note that *model attribute is changed to* `modelAttribute="employee"`, because I mapped it with `new ModelAndView("edit", "employee", new Employee());` in `doBinding(...)` controller)
- I changed `action=..` path to */saveemployee*
- Add `<context:annotation-config />` there in your *spring-servlet.xml* also  `xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"`in `<beans..` to enable it.

  ```
         <%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
          <%@ taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" %>
          <%@taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" prefix="form" %>
          <%@taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
          <html>
          <body>
          <c:if test="${session_username != null }">Hello ${session_username}!</c:if>
              <font face="verdana" size="2">
                  ${welcomeMessage} <BR><BR>
                  <form:form                action="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/saveemployee" method="POST" modelAttribute="employee">
                      <form:errors path="studenterrors" />
                      <table>
                          <tr>
                              <td colspan="2" align="center">Spring MVC Form Demo - Edit</td>
                          </tr>
                          <tr>
                              <td>User Name</td>
                              <td><form:input path="username" /></td>
                          </tr>
                          <tr>
                              <td>First Name</td>
                              <td><form:input path="firstname" /></td>
                          </tr>
                          <tr>
                              <td>Last Name</td>
                              <td><form:input path="lastname" /></td>
                          </tr>
                          <tr>
                              <td>Mobile No.</td>
                              <td><form:input path="mobileno" /></td>
                          </tr>
                          <tr>
                              <td>Password</td>
                              <td><form:password path="password" /></td>
                          </tr>
                          <tr>
                              <td>Email</td>
                              <td><form:input path="email" /></td>
                          </tr>
                          <tr>
                              <td>BirthDate (mm/dd/yyyy)</td>
                              <td><form:input path="birthdate" /></td>
                          </tr>
                          <tr>
                              <td>Profession</td>
                              <td><form:select path="profession" items="${professionList}" /></td>
                          </tr>
                          <tr>
                              <td colspan="2" align="center"><input type="submit" value="Submit" /></td>
                          </tr>                                   
                      </table>                                        
                  </form:form>
              </font> 
          </body>
          </html>
  ```
- Now request the form with  --> *...../employeeform*
- After the form gets submitted it goes to -->  `EditSaveMyInfo()` (*action = "/saveemployee"*)

Note : *I don't expect my answer to directly solve your problem (because the errors could come from somewhere else in your codes), but I just want you to get the binding process in spring mvc*.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. As I already mentioned, I am getting the error because of `<form:input path="birthdate" />`. When I remove this, it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

HTTP STATUS 400 means some thing wrong with the parameters passing from front end to back end. 
`@ModelAttribute` tells get value from session, I suppose to use `@RequestParam` should be used at your situation which is getting parameters from http request.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/editemployee", method=RequestMethod.POST)
public ModelAndView EditSaveMyInfo(ModelMap model, @RequestParam("employee") Employee employee) {
    model.addAttribute("message", "Information Updated");
    return new ModelAndView("EditSuccess",model);
} 

<form:form action="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/editemployee" method="POST">
```

Comment: An error is occurring `neither bindingresult nor plain target object for bean name 'command' available as request attribute` if I remove `modelAttribute`!!

Comment: I suppose to check those parameters one by one then, `BirthDate ` especially. Most of HTTP 400 faults I have got cause by failed model injection or some of the parameters cant be converted.

Comment: You are right, I checked one by one all the textboxes. The problem is with `birthdate` one. When I remove `<form:input path="birthdate" />`, it is working fine. What is the problem with `birthdate`?

Comment: the problem is if using a `text box` to inject `date` type value, that means Spring MVC need to convert  a value from `String` to  `Date`. But not every `String` can be formatted into a `Date` value, but Strings in some specific formats.